# Where does ServiceStack publish vulnerability information?

Tags: security, servicestack

If a vulnerability were to be discovered for any versions 3/4/5 and a patch were to be released - where would ServiceStack publish vulnerability information?

Answer (score 0):

If we've been made aware of a vulnerability we'd resolve it in the next release and include it in the Release Notes, e.g. a vulnerability we were notified about was discovered by Microsoft Vulnerability Research team when [using object properties in DTOs](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.10#vulnerability-with-object-properties).